# Fast Fourier Transform results: frequency axis scale?

Tags: ios, accelerometer, fft, accelerate-framework

I successfully implemented code that takes array data and runs a fast fourier transform on it, using Apple's Accelerate Framework (performed on iOS device).

My question now is what is the scale of the frequency axis?  The results have peaks as expected in certain frequency ranges, but I'm not sure what the frequency should be.  The Accelerate Framework's FFT functions take in an array and spit out an array with the same (or more) number of data points.  Does it assume that all those points are equally spaced in time?  It doesn't take the sampling frequency or time variable as input.  Is the scale of the frequency axis (i.e. frequency increment on each point) just the sampling period divided by 2*Pi (or something similar to that?)  I couldn't find a lot of information in the documentation on this.  I've been looking for similar questions online and haven't found anything.

This is in some ways a math question, although it depends heavily on the Accelerate Framework implementation.

Thanks

EDIT
I asked a follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508692/accelerate-framework-fft-vdspztoc-split-real-form-to-split-real-vector) but no one has answered it yet.  Please take a look!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The FFT gives you linearly spaced frequency bins up to the sampling frequency. This means that the spacing between the bins is (sample frequency) / (number of bins).

Comment: What's a bin?  How big is the bin?

Comment: Each bin is represented by one complex FFT result array element.  The first bin is DC, then space the points as above.

Comment: Thanks.
While we're at it, in an FFT on real data, what does the sign of the FFT data indicate?  Is the positive data real and the negative data imaginary?  I say this because when I ran a simple sine and cosine through the FFT, the cosine gave an impulse pointing up and the sine an impulse pointing down.

Comment: What should you do with the DC component?  Do you plot that?

Comment: @shim It entirely depends on your application. It is a valid data point.

Comment: DC is the same as 0 Hz.  Do you want to start your plot at 0?  Or some other starting point?

Comment: Why wouldn't you start your plot at 0?

Comment: I asked a follow-up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508692/accelerate-framework-fft-vdspztoc-split-real-form-to-split-real-vector) but no one has answered it yet.  Please take a look!

Answer (score 5):

The frequency axis scale does not depend on the Accelerate framework implementation, only on the sample rate (FS) of the time domain data and the length (N) of the FFT.  Any FFT.

For strictly real data input, the second half of the FFT results will just be complex conjugates of the first half.  Only the first half, up to FS/2, are usually plotted for real data.

Comment: Which half?  Is every other data point is the complex conjugate?  Or the second half of the data?  The accelerate framework has functions to pack/unpack data (ztoc, ctoz).  IF I want the real data together, should I not unpack it at the end?

It seems that the complex points are negative and the real is positive.  Does that make sense?  I think that's the case because I did an FFT on sin(t) and cos(t) and the cos had a spike pointing up and the sine had one pointing down.