# Interpreting X axis units in fourier transform

Tags: math, signals, fft, sampling

I understand that there is a sampling frequency and there is a total number of data points. What confuses me is the unit of time. Most of what I see deals with Hz and samples/sec but my samples are done at 15 minute intervals. Suppose I have 4096 data points each at the rate of 15 minutes giving 4096*15=61440 minutes of duration. Then how can I calculate the units of the x axis on the Fourier transform.

Is it `fs = Data points/duration = 4096/(15*4096) = 1/15` samples/minute
and then each bin corresponds to  `1/(4096*15)` minutes?

Or `fs = Data points/duration = 4096/(15*60*4096) = 1/(15*60)` samples/sec
with each bin corresponding to `1/(4096*15*60)` seconds?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272644/fast-fourier-transform-results-frequency-axis-scale?rq=1

Comment: I am tempted to mark this as a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224823/how-exactly-do-you-compute-the-fast-fourier-transform), but it doesn't *directly* offer the information that you need. However, one of the answers contains [this link](http://blogs.zynaptiq.com/bernsee/dft-a-pied/), which I think gives a very good explanation.

Comment: I feel like there is a general solution to this. If I have N samples at the rate of s sample/t unit time, what are the units of the FFT? Quoted on the linked post: "The FFT gives you linearly spaced frequency bins up to the sampling frequency. This means that the spacing between the bins is (sample frequency) / (number of bins)." so my thoughts say the ith bin has frequency (i/N)/(s/t) so that the last bin is (N/N)*(s/t)=s/t. In this particular case N=4096 and s/t=1/15min so each bin is i*15/4096 minutes.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371627/253056) ?